# ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am complete new to Ruby on Rails, with great difficulty I have installed the software on my Windows 8 machine. Now I am just following [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#installing-rails) to create a sample Hello World example.

When I am trying to follow the steps given given in section **4.3 Setting the Application Home Page**, I started facing issue.

Here is what I did:

1) Open the file config/routes.rb in your editor.

2) Uncommented the line `root 'welcome#index'`

3) restarted the server.

Now when I access the URL as `localhost:3000` then I started getting below error on my browser:

```
ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index 

 Showing E:/Rails/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
  (in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)

Extracted source (around line #6):
<head>
<title>Blog</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

Rails.root: E:/Rails/blog
```

Can you please tell me why I am getting this issue?

Also is developing applications using Ruby On Rails is very? because it has been 2 days since I am trying but till now I faced so many issues before I see the Hello World example. I have worked on Java based frameworks but I never faced so much difficulty in installation or creating basic applications.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your **/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb** line 5 and 6, change the first parameter application to default.

Comment: great, it worked. But I lost complete hope on Ruby on Rails, its really bad, the official document itself doesn't tell how to install or create applications properly.

Comment: @Gaurav Gupta
Can you explain what's the problem and why one has to change the parameter for the script to work ?

Comment: Downvoted - didn't explain why the solution worked, which meant I had to figure out why it didn't work for me. (The various link creation tags seem to dynamically create links to particular files already created by default in the assets/ folders, so presumably there existed a version where the default index page tried to access application.css (for example) while default.css was the pre-installed file.)

Answer (score 0):

Although the above solution works (from Gaurav Gupta), the better one would be to downgrade the version of `'coffee-script-source'` to v1.8.0 because the problem comes from the version `1.9.0` and over:

Add in *blog/GemFile* the coffee-script-source v1.8.0 (v1.9.0 does not work on Windows)

```rb
#For Windows it works with CofferScript v1.8
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

Then stop the server (if it was running) and do:

```
bundle update coffee-script-source
```

It should now be working fine.

Replacing the `"application"` by `"default"` in *blog\app\views\layouts\application.html.erb* line 5 and 6 will prevent to load extra files (resulting in CSS and javascript files not used in the page).